# Is there a way I can add code to update a timer list into a class I inherit from?

Tags: c#

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class BaseGridViewModel 
{
    protected BaseGridViewModel() 
    {
        Timer = new List<long>();
    }
    public List<long> Timer { get; set; }
}
public class CityReportViewModel : BaseGridViewModel 
{
    public IEnumerable<City.Grid> Grid { get; set; }
}
```

In my action code I am doing timing like this:

```
        var vm = new CityReportViewModel();
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        try {
            //
            vm.Timer.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            //
            vm.Timer.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            //
            // Lots more vm.Timer.Add lines ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log(e);
        } finally {
            sw.Stop();
        }
```

Because I do a lot of timing I have the vm.Timer.Add code repeated many times in my controllers.

Is there some way I could simplify the timer coding by making a change to the ViewModels. The kind of thing I am thinking of is to set up the timer as a field in the ViewModels and then have some way of telling the ViewModel that I want to record a new timing event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure about your requirement, but it sounds like you need an observer.
Your 'BaseGridViewModel' may register himself to an obeserver. The observer raises may an event to update all timers in all attached BaseGridViewModels.

### Edit

This is what I'm talking about:

```
 public class TimerUpdateService
    {
        public TimerUpdateService()
        {
            // May create here a Stopwatch to measure your time.
        }

        private EventHandler<EventArgs> _updater;

        public void Register(BaseGridViewModel baseGridViewModel)
        {
            _updater += baseGridViewModel.timerUpdate_UpDateTimers;
        }

        public void Unregister(BaseGridViewModel baseGridViewModel)
        {
            _updater -= baseGridViewModel.timerUpdate_UpDateTimers;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Call this method to refresh all timers on the registred 'BaseGridViewModel'.
        /// </summary>
        public void UpdateAllViewModels()
        {
            EventHandler<EventArgs> handler = _updater;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

    }

    public abstract class BaseGridViewModel
    {
        protected BaseGridViewModel()
        {
            Timer = new List<long>();
        }

        public void timerUpdate_UpDateTimers(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer.Add(e.elapsed);
        }

        public List<long> Timer { get; set; }

    }


    public class CityReportViewModel : BaseGridViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<City.Grid> Grid { get; set; }


    }
```

May this is what you need. The above code is only an example..

Comment: I was thinking of a method in the viewmodel that I could call to update the timer. I am just not so sure how to code that.

Comment: ` vm.Timer.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);` is correct, but if you tell me more about your requirement or when you have to update the timer, may there is a better solution.

Comment: I update the timer many time in each action and in many actions and many controllers. I am just trying to cut down on the amount of typing. I'd love some way of updating the timer that just involved my typing vm.Time().   I know there is very little difference between that and vm.Timer.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);  but having a shortform way to record a time step doesn't clutter my code so much. Thanks.